# java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException

Tags: java, swing, illegalstateexception

I'm getting `java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException` at line 103 i.e.

```
guiFrame.setLocationByPlatform(true)
```

Any ideas as to how to resolve it? During instance creation I'm enclosing it in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` method but still it's popping up.

Code is pasted below :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import chrriis.common.UIUtils;
import chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface;
import chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.components.JWebBrowser;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class CardLayoutExample {

    JFrame guiFrame = new JFrame();

    CardLayout cards = new CardLayout();

    JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel();

    JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();

    private JPanel tabsPanel = new JPanel();

    static boolean isYoutube = false;

    static boolean isGmail = false;

    private ImageIcon animatedGif;

    private static final String FIRST_PANEL = "First Panel";

    /*
     * public static void main(String[] args) {
     * 
     * // EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     * 
     * @Override public void run() {
     * 
     * new CardLayoutExample(); } });
     * 
     * }
     */
    public CardLayoutExample() {

        guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        guiFrame.setTitle("Services");
        guiFrame.setSize(400, 300);
        guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        guiFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        guiFrame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        Border outline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);

        tabsPanel.setBorder(outline);
        tabsPanel.setLayout(cards);

        JLabel services = new JLabel("Please choose from the services below :-");
        JButton youtube = new JButton();
        youtube.setName("youtube");

        ImageIcon youtubeIcon = new ImageIcon("images/youtube_icon.jpg");
        youtube.setIcon(youtubeIcon);
        youtube.setBorder(outline);

        youtube.setRolloverEnabled(true);
        animatedGif = new ImageIcon("images/plnttm.gif");
        youtube.setRolloverIcon(animatedGif);

        youtube.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                isGmail = false;
                isYoutube = true;

                NativeInterface.open();
                UIUtils.setPreferredLookAndFeel();

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                        cardPanel.removeAll();
                        cardPanel.add(createContentYoutube(),
                                BorderLayout.NORTH);

                        guiFrame.setSize(800, 600);
                        guiFrame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                        guiFrame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                        guiFrame.setVisible(true);
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        JButton gmail = new JButton();
        gmail.setName("gmail");

        ImageIcon gmailIcon = new ImageIcon("images/Gmail_Icon.png");
        gmail.setIcon(gmailIcon);
        gmail.setBorder(outline);

        gmail.setRolloverEnabled(true);
        animatedGif = new ImageIcon("images/plnttm.gif");
        gmail.setRolloverIcon(animatedGif);

        gmail.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                isGmail = true;
                isYoutube = false;

                NativeInterface.open();
                UIUtils.setPreferredLookAndFeel();

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                        cardPanel.removeAll();
                        cardPanel.add(createContentGmail(), BorderLayout.NORTH);

                        guiFrame.setSize(800, 600);
                        guiFrame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                        guiFrame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                        guiFrame.setVisible(true);
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
        box.add(services);
        box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));
        box.add(youtube);
        box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20));
        box.add(gmail);

        firstPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
        firstPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        firstPanel.add(box);

        tabsPanel.add(firstPanel, FIRST_PANEL);

        cardPanel.setLayout(cards);
        cards.show(cardPanel, "Web Browser");

        guiFrame.setVisible(true);
        guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        guiFrame.add(tabsPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        guiFrame.add(cardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        guiFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static JComponent createContentYoutube() {
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel webBrowserPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        webBrowserPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory
                .createTitledBorder("Web Browser"));
        final JWebBrowser webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
        webBrowser.navigate("http://youtube.com");
        webBrowserPanel.add(webBrowser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        webBrowser.setBarsVisible(false);
        contentPane.add(webBrowserPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 4, 4));
        contentPane.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        return contentPane;
    }

    public static JComponent createContentGmail() {
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel webBrowserPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        webBrowserPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory
                .createTitledBorder("Web Browser"));
        final JWebBrowser webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
        webBrowser.navigate("http://gmail.com");
        webBrowserPanel.add(webBrowser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        webBrowser.setBarsVisible(false);
        contentPane.add(webBrowserPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 4, 4));
        contentPane.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        return contentPane;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the [expected exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationByPlatform%28boolean%29) when calling `setLocationByPlatform(true)` after having already called `setVisible(true)`. A *single* call to `setVisible()` should be sufficient.